# Bash Echo 4-step indentation

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run this script to a file and I would like to add 4-step indent before each of the bullet points. Right now it seems to be doing a smaller indentation for the bullet points.

```
echo -e "\nHEADING
bullet point 1
bullet point 2
bullet point 3" >> todo.txt
```

Desired result todo.txt:

```
HEADING
    bullet point 1
    bullet point 2
    bullet point 3
```

How can I apply the 4-step indent to only the last 3 lines only?

Comment: Can you not manually add spaces for some reason?

Comment: use `\t` at the beginning of newlines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using quotes already. Just format it the way you want it to look.

```
$: echo "
HEADING
    bullet point 1
    bullet point 2
    bullet point 3
"

HEADING
    bullet point 1
    bullet point 2
    bullet point 3
```

Does the same if you send to a file.

```
$: echo "
HEADING
    bullet point 1
    bullet point 2
    bullet point 3
" >file
$: cat file

HEADING
    bullet point 1
    bullet point 2
    bullet point 3
```